# How to obtain a "global" class object in C++ via `extern`

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

I checked several answers on the forums about this topic, but for some reason I still cannot wrap my mind about the problem and get my works running.

My aim is to have one object of a class available in all translation units. Note, I do not seek to implement a singleton pattern here. There can be multiple instances of the class, but there will always be at least *one* and this one can be seen where "its header" is included.

Assume a design like this:

```
---logging.h---
class LogCenter {
...
}

class Logger {
private:
  LogCenter& center;
public:
  Logger();  //automatically assigns the ominous global LogCenter object (reference) to center.
  Logger(LogCenter&);  //however, any other LogCenter object would work equally fine.
}
```

The reason? I want that all `Logger`s can use this global `LogCenter` per default, wherever they may be used.
But now I'm unsure how to provide this global `LogCenter`. It has the default constructor. Do I just add a line `extern LogCenter globalCenter;` into the `logging.h` file and another `LogCenter globalCenter;` line into the `logging.cpp` file? Or just `LogCenter globalCenter;` in the `logging.cpp` and `extern LogCenter globalCenter;` in any file that uses it?

I am really confused, none of which I tried worked - however, the overall code works fine when I use the constructor overload with its own `LogCenter` instance.

---

EDIT: Important: `extern` goes with declaration (e.g. in header file). Then one single definition in an implementation file.

Check *all* the answers!

---

This is how it works:

```
---logging.h---
class Entry;

class LogCenter {
friend class Logger;  //please don't bash my friend design right away... D:
private:
  list<Entry> entries;
public:
  void printLog(string file);
}

extern LogCenter SCenter;

class Logger {
private:
  LogCenter& center;
public:
  Logger();  //uses extern or "singleton" object.
  Logger(LogCenter&);
  void commitEntry(Entry);  //adds the Entry object to the list in the center object.
}
-----------------

---logging.cpp---
#include "logging.h"
LogCenter SCenter;

void Logger::commitEntry(Entry e) {
  entries.push_back(e);  //Logger can access LogCenter fields!
}

void LogCenter::printLog(string file) {
  //open file stream str
  for(list<Entry>::iterator it = entries.begin();...)
    str << it->getEntry() << endl;
  //close file
}
--------------

---main.cpp---
#include "logging.h"

int main() {
  Logger log;
  Entry e("Some entry");
  log.commitEntry(e);
  SCenter.printLog("filename.log");

  //or
  LogCenter cent;
  Logger log(cent);
  Entry e("some entry");
  log.commitEntry(e);
  cent.printLog("filename.log");

  return 0;
}
-------------
```

Comment: A "pseudo-singleton" implementation could be a work around...however, I'm eager to learn how what I want to achieve actually works...

Comment: I don't see how the `LogCenter` instance is different from a singleton.

Comment: As far as I know a singleton pattern results in there being _one and only one_ instance. I want _one specific/always and an arbitrary number of others_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use the following C++ singleton pattern which is easy to use and even safe when using it across shared libraries:

```
// LogCenter.h
class /*API_MACRO_FOR_EXPORTING*/ LogCenter {
public:
    static LogCenter* instance();
}

// For quick access you could define a macro
#define sLogCenter \
    LogCenter::instance()

// LogCenter.cpp
LogCenter* LogCenter::instance()
{
    static LogCenter instance;
    return &instance;
}

// LogCenter::instance()->DoSomething();

// sLogCenter->DoSomething();
```

To answer your question about extern:

```
// LogCenter.h
// You can use multiple definitions with extern so the compiler
// knows the LogCenter is instantiated somewhere else.
extern LogCenter globalCenter;

// LogCenter.cpp
// Only 1 declaration of LogCenter
/*API_MACRO_FOR_EXPORTING*/ LogCenter globalCenter;
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you chose pointers over references? But I would still have the constructor `public` to make other instances available, right?
The macro definition would also be in the header, I guess? Why would my approach be problematic in a shared library scenario? --- About `extern`: This is exactly what I tried to do, but it doesn't work! It compiles, it runs, but it doesn't behave as expected, whereas it works fine with a "not global" `LogCenter` instance... :(

Comment: Yes, i prefer pointers over references for non stack variables (It won't make any difference since references are converted to pointers anyway). Yes you are right, the macro belongs to the header i will correct it. Declare variables in header files is always problematic but when using shared libraries it will lead to massive duplicated singleton instances (as like when declaring variables as static inside methods in linux). Another advantage of the instance approach is that you can't mess up those extern declarations (it's just easy to use).

Comment: About your 2. edit: You could show us more details about your code if you still having issues.

Comment: Ah, I see that non-stack argument... but it would work with references, though, wouldn't it? So I'd have to change the class definition of Logger to `LogCenter* center;`, right? --- Shared Library: Ah, yeah, I read about that already, that's of course an argument against the `extern` approach. Would there be an `extern` solution solving the shared library problem?

Comment: Yep, I will edit in some detail about the code. Still, I'm very interested in the concepts and designs in general, not only the solution for the particular problem. Although concepts and designs are often well discussed in the light of an actual problem. :D

Comment: No extern won't be an issue when you export your variable correctly (using visibility or declspec(export)) from your code.

Comment: Okay...invisibility and declspec(export) are things I will further investigate... but from this statement one can derive that for now the "extended singleton" approach might be the one to choose... --- I added a rough version of what I'm doing (feel free to say something about the `friend` approach...) but while typing the example I discovered what a f**** dimwit I was... In the main I was still using the local instance of `LogCenter` to print a log, even when I was trying out the global one --> no log file, because no commited entries... So stupid. It was more or less correct all the time!

Answer (score 3):

Using an `extern` variable is one option.

Another option is to have a function that returns a reference.

logging.h:

```
LogCenter& getGlobalLogCenter();
```

logging.cpp:

```
LogCenter& getGlobalLogCenter()
{
   static LogCenter lc;
   return lc;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this approach is what I meant in my comment and would work, I guess. However, I'm confused - I though `static` causes internal linkage... How do other translation units know about it? One can see that I've still not wrapped my mind about all this... Shouldn't this function be `static` as well?? And how would one correctly implement the `extern` variable (this is my main problem!). Thanks!

Comment: The other translation units can use the function without any problem, if they `#include` logger.h. The function needs to be `static` it is a member function of `LogCenter`. If it is a global function, then it must not be `static`.

Comment: Use of `extern` variable is quite simple. You declare the variable in the .h file and make sure you have the definition in the appropriate .cpp file.

Comment: So in the class definition I would have a `public static Logcenter& getGlobalLogCenter();` declaration... --- Ah, sure, of course including makes the function available. :) --- Just to be sure: declaration goes with `extern` keyword, definition in the appropriate (and ONLY there) cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

```
//logcenter.h
#ifndef LOGCENTER_H_
#define LOGCENTER_H_

class LogCenter {
private:
    int dummy;
public:
    int getVal(){ return dummy; };
    LogCenter() : dummy(0){};
    LogCenter(int val) : dummy(val) {};
};

#endif  // LOGCENTER_H_
```

xxx

```
// logcenter.cpp
#include "LogCenter.h"

LogCenter globalCenter;
```

xxx

```
//logger.h
#ifndef LOGGER_H_
#define LOGGER_H_

#include <string>
#include "LogCenter.h"

class Logger {
private:
  LogCenter& center;
public:
  Logger();  //automatically assigns the ominous global LogCenter object (reference) to center.
  Logger(LogCenter&);  //however, any other LogCenter object would work equally fine.
  std::string print() { return std::string("This class uses logger ") + std::to_string(center.getVal()); };
};

#endif // LOGCENTER_H
```

xxx

```
// logger.cpp
#include "Logger.h"

extern LogCenter globalCenter;

Logger::Logger() : center(globalCenter) {};

Logger::Logger(LogCenter &logcenter) : center(logcenter) {};
```

xxx

```
// main.cpp
#include "Logger.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    LogCenter logcenter2(2), logcenter3(3);
    Logger logger1, logger2(logcenter2), logger3(logcenter3);

    std::cout << logger1.print() << std::endl;
    std::cout << logger2.print() << std::endl;
    std::cout << logger3.print() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
This class uses logger 0
This class uses logger 2
This class uses logger 3
```

Comment: Well this is quite on point! `main.cpp` needs no `LogCenter.h` inclusion because `Logger.h` has it already, right?

Comment: @LCsa right. I think needs the header for cout though. Anyway i dunno why people don't answer the question you posed, and write answers to their own questions instead.

Comment: Yeah, but I am very thankful anyways, because my question got answered in the end AND new/even better approaches came on the table. Your approch differs from mine in that you just put a wild `globalCenter` into the `LogCenter.h` and refer to that in the `Logger.h`, whereas I declare the existence of the global object in the `LogCenter.h`! Is there an important difference? Because intuitively I would favor my version because the `LogCenter.h` then clearly states: "Hey guys, I'm `LogCenter` and there will _always_ be my `extern` object for you guys!" Your's expects the `Logger.h`to know about it

Comment: I'm not sure i understood what you mean, to clarify anyway:
1) classes definitions are in logger.h and logcenter.h
2) note that the 2 definitions are in different files, so you can include them indipendently
3) the global instance globalCenter is in logcenter.cpp 
4) extern is used in logger.cpp, but could have been placed inside logger.h instead

Comment: What I meant was that declaring `extern LogCenter globalCenter;` in the `LogCenter.h` and defining it `LogCenter globalCenter;` in the `LogCenter.cpp` would clearly state the existence and the usage of such a global object. "Hey guys, I'm LogCenter and there will always be my extern global object for you!" Whereas declaring the `extern` in the _using_ header `Logger.h` could raise the question: "How can I be so sure there is a global object at all? Why should I assume that."... I think it's rather a conceptual than a technical question.

Comment: Does having the `extern` part in any header bring the problem in the light of shared libraries pointed out by @Denis Blank?

Comment: maybe this link can help: http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1321396234&id=1043284376

Comment: "Whereas declaring the extern in the using header Logger.h could raise the question..." note that is used logger.cpp, not h. I would put it where it is used (because i suppose is not needed anywhere), but if you need the global version in thousands of files than put it in the header.

Comment: I, for now, accepted Denis Blank's answer, because of the discussion of the concept, etc. He also provided a very simple `extern` example at the bottom. Nevertheless, your answer is also very good and demonstrates the `extern` usage well and if I could, I'd choose both of them. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second option, that is, "extern LogCenter globalCenter;" in the file where ever it is used.

The reason, if someone is including logging.h, may be for creating the new object of Logcenter class, but does not intend to use the globalCenter object, then why he needs the extern declaration for globalCenter object.

Comment: How would the declaration in the header/implementation file look like if I wanted to go that way? However, if this user does not declare `extern.....` like you stated but calls the `Logger()` constructor, we have a problem, no?